# Index.html won't show content of the file

Tags: html, firebase, localhost, firebase-hosting

I took some sample files from a repository, loaded them into firebase hosting, and when i do `firebase serve` it loads an empty page for `localhost:5000`. However, if I do `localhost:5000/public/index.html`, it shows this: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rigj.jpg). What is the error here? I am confused. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Did you run `firebase use --add` in your `web-start` directory before running `firebase serve`? Have you tried `firebase serve --only hosting` instead of `firebase serve`?

Comment: @MatthewSmith 1. I don't have a `web-start` directory, am I supposed to have that? I initialized with `firebase init` with the Node.js command prompt. 2. When I do that, it gives me the `<title>` of it but still see an empty body.

Comment: Can I ask what repository you got your sample files from and possibly the link?

Comment: I made a second html file that works and loads properly, could it be the index.html file? https://github.com/bcook12345/firebase-web-login/tree/master

Comment: It could be the `index.html`. Are you trying to set up an email and password authentication system? If so, I would recommend working through an official sample from Google such as https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/README.md

Comment: Okay, I'll look into that. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. For a more detailed look into authentication and other Firebase features I would also suggest working through a Codelab (a list can be found here -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/)

Comment: Thanks so much @MatthewSmith